# For Loop repeats first loop twice

Tags: javascript, loops

I have this for loop, and it seems to be repeating the first loop twice (x=0) and then not doing the last one (x=2)

```
for (x=0;x<=2;x++)
    {
        if (document.getElementById("sub"+catCount+x).value != "")
        {
            if (nonums.test(document.getElementById("sub"+catCount+x).value))
            {
                total = total + parseFloat(document.getElementById("sub"+catCount+x).value);
            }
        }
        alert(x);
    }
```

In other words, I get two alert boxes with "0" in them, then one with "1" in it, and that's it.

Can anyone tell me what I'm not seeing here? Why doesn't it just progress through the loop normally (0,1,2)?

Comment: Given that x is (possibly) declared as a global, does anything else in the functions you have called alter it?

Comment: This part of the code is not causing the problem. Can you point us to a URL of the whole site?

Comment: that is literally the only spot I use the variable x on any page.

Comment: @phihag: I can't, really. I'd need to give you a login.

Comment: what happens if you change the variable name?

Comment: try moving the alert to top of the if statements, to see if they're causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that is literally the only spot I use
>   the variable x on any page.

[It works for me](http://jsbin.com/osepo).

```
for (x=0;x<=2;x++)
{
  alert(x);
}
```

You can test it at console.

Comment: @Jimmy: It says `0` then `1` and `2` for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want the variable x to be global in scope.  Try it with the "var" keyword:

```
for (var x=0;x<=2;x++)
...
```

I can paste this in my address bar and it will produce 0, 1, 2.

```
javascript:for (var x=0;x<=2;x++) {alert(x);}
```

I tried it in IE, FF and Chrome.