# For loop repeating first iteration twice

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, sum

I am having an issue with a javascript for loop. I am adding up the elements of an array, but for some reason my loop adds in the first entry twice! There was a similar topic on here before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121670/for-loop-repeats-first-loop-twice) but the author didn't go into his resolution in detail, just that it was "somethin stupid" he did. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing stupid??

```
for(j=0;j<ARRAY.length;j++)
{TOTAL += ARRAY[j];}
```

The output is used in a HTML table and it is displaying correctly, it's just the doubled first entry that's the issue!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well it shouldn't make any difference in this case, but you should make sure that "j" is declared with `var`.  Your loop will definitely not repeat the first iteration.

Comment: @Karl Major: also go through some of your previous questions and accept answer that were helpful to you

Comment: Are the first two entries in `ARRAY` identical?

Comment: @Jack Maney - Yes it is.

Comment: @Pointy - adding var doesn't fix my problem, I had already tried that, hence my utter confusion.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker - No they are not, but would that even matter? In that case I would imagine the result would show triple the figure.

Comment: OK, well, the fact remains that there is simply no way that that "for" loop, as posted, will repeat its first iteration. I suggest you reexamine the evidence you have that leads you to the conclusion that it does.

Comment: @Pointy - I wish that was the case but I can assure you it does not work. As I said below to Graeme, I have added a new variable equal to TOTAL-ARRAY[0] and this gives me the correct anwer. The issue may be that I am coding in SharePoint and normal sense doesn't apply much. Thank you, however, for your input; I at least know that I was on the right track with my original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all of your help. Since my original approach hit a dead end I looked into using a function to do the trick. The following works:

```
Array.prototype.sum = function() {
for (var j = 0, L = this.length, sum = 0; j < L; sum += this[j++]);
return sum;
}
```

I then call ARRAY.sum() when creating my html table.

I found the above solution on http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=218803

Answer (score 2):

`var TOTAL = 0;
    for ( var j = 0, len = ARRAY.length; j < len; j++ ) {
        TOTAL += ARRAY[j];
    }`

MDN suggest to use a variable to hold the array length. In addition check your scripts with [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your response @Bakudan but unfortunately this renders the same result as before! I don't know what's happening. Thanks also for JSLint, I had never heard of this before. in this case though it merely pointed out some formattin errors in my code and produced no remedy for my issue.

Comment: @KarlMajor the snippet you've provided is too small to find anything else.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you declare with var...

Nice little bit of prompting debugging in there too.

```
for(var j=0; j < ARRAY.length; j++) {
{
    TOTAL += ARRAY[j];
    //alert("The count of J is now " + j);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the debugging tip @Graeme but unfortunately adding var does not fix my problem. I am beginning to lose hope. For the time being I have declared a new variable equal to TOTAL-ARRAY[0] which gives the correct figure but this is obviously very messy.